# Is it possiable to dynamic loading Android driver module?

Tags: android, module, driver

I'm developing a  function,which is when the moile connect with PC via USB,the moile will display a UI,that have two options "Charging " & "As a mass Storage" .
So I was wondering is it possiable  to achieve the goal by dynamic insmod or rmmod the USB and SD card module?
And if Android linux support dynamic load module, How to communicate with linux?(By jni?)

I have no idea ,Can anyone give me some advice?

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about ordinary 3rd party app, then you can not dynamically load drivers. Android does not allows this kind of activities for third party apps.